# Keras: ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been using the famous dogs-vs-cats kaggle dataset and trying to come up with my own CNN Model. I'm new to using the `image_dataset_from_directory` method to import the dataset after configuring it into two folders that contain the cat and dog images separately.

Here is the code for the model.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,\
     Dropout,Flatten,Dense,Activation,\
     BatchNormalization
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And here's the code for the dataset:

```
Dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="binary",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(128, 128),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    validation_split=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

After running the fit function to train my CNN. I was shown this error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:748 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1605 binary_crossentropy
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4823 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py:173 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        raise ValueError("logits and labels must have the same shape (%s vs %s)" %

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It has to do something with the target size of the image. I also ran up to this error earlier but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: The `input shape = (128,128,3)` and the `image_size = (128,128)` is causing the error.

Comment: But the rgb specification takes care of that right? I just ran the code with `input_shape = (128,128,3)` and it didn't work since that argument requires a 2D-vector.

Comment: Yes, it should but I don't know why is it happening. I have the identical error too.

Comment: try setting Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') as last layer instead of Dense(2,activation='sigmoid')

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense though. The last layer should have two neurons to identify if the photo is (100% cat,  0% dog) vice versa.

Comment: binary classification with sigmoid (the basic of the basic)... if up 0.5 is class 1 if below is class 0 :-)

Comment: oh sorry. I'm just new to AI. sorryy

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my question!
I managed to train the model by setting the loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead of `binary_crossentropy`. Then I also changed the activation function of the last layer to `softmax` that was `sigmoid` when I asked the question.

Here's the whole code if you're interested:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,\
     Dropout,Flatten,Dense,Activation,\
     BatchNormalization
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```